# multiple variables in NSLog Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I'm having some trouble getting two or more variables showing up in the NSLog.

This works:

```
int var1 = 10;
int var2 = 2;

NSLog(@"this is a variable: %d", var1);
```

but this doesn't:

```
int var1 = 10;
int var2 = 2;

NSLog(@"this is a variable: %d", var1, " and heres another %d", var2);
```

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, and not entirely sure how the whole `%d` thing works either.  A not overly complicated explanation that's light on jargon would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry, don't know what happened with the spacing on my variable definitions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should write it like this

```
NSLog(@"this is a variable: %d  and   heres another %d",var1, var2);
```

Comment: I'm guessing you need to reference the variables in the order they're mentioned? thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes,you need mention in sequence.Please accept if it helped